# Update Column Field ONLY If Empty (PostgreSQL)

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL in conjunction with PHP for a project.

```sql
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

$result = pg_query($dbconn, "UPDATE target.table
    SET activated = true, activated_timestamp = NOW() 
    WHERE (activated IS NULL)
    AND email = '$email'");

if (!$result) {
  echo "already activated or invalid email!";
  exit;
} else {
    echo "updated!";
}
```

I have `target.table` containing users that can activate their account by entering their email address (POST request via form).

In the table, each user (with the unique identifier of email address) has two fields associated with him: `activated` and `activated_timestamp`.

The code above works and only updates the table if the user has ***not*** been activated before.

***But*** `$result` still returns `true`. Thus, upon form submission, the page echoes `updated!` instead of `already activated …` and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the function returns a resource that represents the query result.  It only returns FALSE if an error occurs.

Try using `if (pg_affected_rows($result) == 0)` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php `pg_query` returns FALSE only in case when there was an error, otherwise resource is returned which casted to boolean is always TRUE. You should use `pg_affected_rows($result)` to find out if any record was changed because of your query.